# ¿Cómo buscar dos columnas a la vez en el mismo Input usando Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-6

Tengo un input en el cual puedo buscar nombre o apellido, pero no puedo buscar nombre y apellido a la vez... esta es mi función

```
    public function resultados_asesores(Request $request){
  $busqueda = $request->asesor;
  $asesores = strtoupper($busqueda);
  $perimetro = DB::table('tbl_perimetros as a')
    ->select('a.id', 'a.rif', 'a.cod_cliente', 'a.razon_social', 'a.holdings_id')
    ->leftjoin('tbl_holdings as b', 'b.id', '=', 'a.holdings_id')
    ->leftjoin('tbl_equipo_postventaatcs as c', 'c.id', '=', 'a.postventaatc_id')
    ->leftjoin('users as e', 'e.id', '=', 'c.asesor_id')
    ->select(['a.id', 'b.hrif', 'b.hrazon_social', 'a.rif', 'a.razon_social', 'a.estatus'])
    ->where('e.name', 'like', '%'.$asesores.'%')
    ->orWhere('e.apellido', 'like', '%'.$asesores.'%')
    ->orWhere('e.idop', 'like', '%'.$asesores.'%')
    ->get();

  if($perimetro->count()) {


    return view('Busqueda.resultados_busquedag',compact('perimetro','busqueda'));
  }


    return view('Busqueda.index');
}
```

Con esta función puedo encontrar nombre o apellido... pero no puedo buscar nombre y apellido a la vez

Este es el input que estoy usando para la busqueda:

```
<form id="asesor" class="form-horizontal" action="{{route('resultados_asesores')}}" method="post">
@csrf
<div class="form-group row">
  <label class="col-md-6 col-form-label" for="asesor"></label>
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <input form="asesor" maxlength="100" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" id="asesor" type="text" name="asesor" placeholder="Introduzca el nombre, apellido o IDOP del asesor a buscar">
    <br>
    <div class="pull-right">
    <button form="asesor" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" type="submit">
      Buscar</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Tienes usuarios con la misma palabra en el nombre y en el apellido?

Comment: Si... quisiera hacer la busqueda con el Nombre y Apellido a la vez... pero se encuentran en columnas diferentes en mi tabla

Comment: Otro problema que tengo es que solo al poner dos letras de algun nombre me busca todo... y solo quiero que la busqueda funcione con nombre y apellido a la vez para que haga el match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo que deseas es que la búsqueda encuentre el mismo término en el nombre y en el apellido, entonces puedes utilizar dos veces el método where():

```
->where('e.name', 'like', '%'.$asesores.'%')
->where('e.apellido', 'like', '%'.$asesores.'%')
```

Comment: Ya lo he intentado amigo.. pero por alguna razon me salta al else que en este caso me retorna esta vista return view('Busqueda.index');

Comment: Entonces estás haciendo mal la consulta.

Comment: la cosa es que si los busco por separado si me funciona

Comment: gracias amigo !